# Using of YouTube Data API v3

Tags: javascript, java, .net, sql-server

In frames of our project we need to use **YouTube Data API v3**. Currently we are in researching process, and we would like to get information about how many requests we may send throw YouTube Data API v3 per day.

I will highly appreciate if you can assist and provide such information.

Thank You,
Vardan

Comment: You can get this information from the YouTube Api documentation which is publicly available online.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank You! I've tried to find such information in available documentations, and didn't find such requirements.

Comment: Thank You @guillermochamorro